# Python : Plot heatmap for large matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar

I have a large matrix of size 500 X 18904.

**Since most of the values are zeros, I'm not able to visualise the pattern clearly as the zeroes dominate in the colorbar.**

To look at the data more closely, I need to zoom in for different segments of image. Is there any reliable way to visualise this data using colorbar?.

Here is my code and output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sio
j = sio.loadmat('UV_matrix.mat')
k = j['UV']  
plt.imshow(k, aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

The output 
[image]

Comment: Can you ignore zero values and normalize using the minimum value other than 0?

Comment: Try histogram equalization: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_equalize.html

Comment: ignored the zero. I can able to see only small black dots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of two options by using numpy arrays.

1. Assuming your data is mostly higher than zero but there are a lot of zeros.:

   ```
   vmin = some_value_higher_than_zero
   plt.matshow(k,aspect='auto',vmin=vmin)
   ```
2. Setting all zeros to NaNs. they are automatically left out.

   ```
   k[k==0.0]=np.nan
   plt.matshow(k,aspect='auto')
   ```

NB. imshow and matshow work both here.

Another option, when your matrix is really sparse is to use scatterplots.

```
x,y = k.nonzero()
plt.scatter(x,y,s=100,c=k[x,y]) #color as the values in k matrix
```

Comment: Just in case anyone comes here looking to fix a problem with charts using sparse time, use `.values` on the times to pass them in as floats, which will then automatically be converted to dates. (It seems both input parameters x and y need to be the same types)